# pyspark (spark 2.2) write streaming dataframe to Mysql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing an structured streaming app that processes data from Kafka source. I'm able to write final processed dataframe to console but I'm struggling in writing that dataframe into mysql db.

In structured streaming via pyspark, is it possible to write dataframe to mysql?

Sketch of my application as follows:

## 1. Create DataSet representing the stream of input lines from kafka

```
df = spark \
.readStream \
.format('kafka') \
.option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', brokers) \
.option(subscribe_type, topic) \
.option('includeTimestamp', 'true') \
.load()
```

## 2. Do ETL in dataframe df.

## 3. Write df to Console:

```
query = df \
.writeStream \
.format('console') \
.option('truncate', 'false') \
.trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
.start()
```

## 4. Export that df to our mysql sink.

Can you please give me an example to do step #4?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution?